# How to remove extensions from ListBox

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I have a piece of code that searches for shortcuts and puts them into a listbox. How can I modify it in order to display the information without the `.lnk` extension

```
For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("Z:\SiteServices\Maintenance\Maintenance Support Folder\Equipment Specific Information\DES", Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*" & txtSearch.Text & "*" & ".lnk")
    ListBox1.Items.Add(foundFile)
Next
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at usinng [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

> Returns the file name of the specified path string without the
>   extension.